# how to inherit model with json Mapping functionality?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I want to create model like below

is it possible to create **model inheritance with Matle/JSON Model framework** ?

ex.

```
@interface basePropertyModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,readwrite) int pid;
@property (nonatomic) contactModel *mContact; // contact is also model 

@end

@interface projectModel : basePropertyModel

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *date_launch,*type_specifications;

end
```

Q.1)Please suggest me best way to use model
Q.2)Can i assign value of json response dict directly to my model as example ContactModel which can be directly assign json response dict.

Thanks & regards

Comment: "is it possible to create model inheritance with Matle/JSON Model framework ?" ==> Yes ,  
"Can i assign value of json response dict directly to my model?" ==> Yes,
"Please suggest me best way to use model" ==> https://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Comment: Thanks Piyush I think u miss understood my query ... I want to inherit model into model + also want to jsonKeyMapping (which is like Matle/JSON Model provide) ...